# <could not resolve type> when debugging Swift 5.1 with LLDB in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu, debugging, lldb

I am trying to debug swift code with lldb in linux and I am failing to do it.

When i try to check for more complex Struct variables i am getting ""

I tried the same with older version and i get the same result, I guess I am missing some config with this

I have simple code from swift documentation

```
struct Celsius {
    var temperatureInCelsius: Double
    init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
    }
}
let bpOfWater = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
let fpOfWater = Celsius(fromKelvin: 273.15)
print("\(bpOfWater)")
print("\(fpOfWater)")
```

using lldb

```
$ which lldb
/usr/share/swift/usr/bin/lldb
$ lldb ./swift/apptest/.build/debug/apptest
(lldb) target create "./swift/apptest/.build/debug/apptest"
Current executable set to './swift/apptest/.build/debug/apptest' (x86_64).
(lldb) b -f main.swift -l 13
Breakpoint 1: where = apptest`main + 504 at main.swift:13:7, address = 0x0000000000001078
(lldb) r
Process 8061 launched: '/home/ubuntu/swift/apptest/.build/debug/apptest' (x86_64)
Celsius(temperatureInCelsius: 100.0)
Process 8061 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'apptest', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000555555555078 apptest`main at main.swift:13:7
   10   let bpOfWater = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
   11   let fpOfWater = Celsius(fromKelvin: 273.15)
   12   print("\(bpOfWater)")
-> 13   print("\(fpOfWater)")
Target 0: (apptest) stopped.
(lldb) frame variable bpOfWater
bpOfWater = <could not resolve type>
(lldb) frame variable fpOfWater
fpOfWater = <could not resolve type>
(lldb)
```

So as you can see I get: could not resolve type

```
(lldb) frame variable bpOfWater
bpOfWater = <could not resolve type>
(lldb) frame variable fpOfWater
fpOfWater = <could not resolve type>
(lldb)
```

and this is not the case with String or Int

So, can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement isn't going to give you anything readable. Try printing out bpOfWater.temperatureInCelsius

Comment: Doesn't help : (lldb) frame variable bpOfWater.temperatureInCelsius - 
error: "temperatureInCelsius" is not a member of "(<invalid type>) bpOfWater"

Comment: Have you tried cleaning everything and recompiling?  Also try explicit declaration: let bpOfWater : Celsius = Celsius(....)